# Woocommerce Product Dynamic Schema Markup

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, schema

I've the next code to dynamic add Schema Markup for WooCommerce Products:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'schema_product');
function schema_product(){
global $product;
if (is_singular('product')) {  ?>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "<?php echo $product->get_name(); ?>",
      "description": "Ver descripción en el link incluido.",
      "image": "<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product->get_id(), 'full' ); ?>",
      "url": "<?php echo get_permalink( $product->get_id() ); ?>",
      "sku": "<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>",
      "brand": "<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'brand', TRUE); ?>",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>",
        "price": "<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>",
        "priceValidUntil": "2019-12-31",
        "priceCurrency": "<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>",
        "url": "<?php echo get_permalink( $product->get_id() ); ?>"
        },
      "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "reviewCount": "3"
        },
      "review": {
          "author": "Federico",
          "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "ratingValue": "5",
            "worstRating": "4"
          }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php  }
};
```

But when the code runs, the result is a merely

> pe

In other schema types, like front page o blog posts, everything is running ok. But it seems that in one place PHP is fighting with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code… Try the following instead:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'schema_product');
function schema_product(){
    global $product;

    if ( is_product() && ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    if ( is_product() && is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) :

    ?>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "<?php echo $product->get_name(); ?>",
      "description": "Ver descripción en el link incluido.",
      "image": "<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product->get_id(), 'full' ); ?>",
      "url": "<?php echo get_permalink( $product->get_id() ); ?>",
      "sku": "<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>",
      "brand": "<?php echo $product->get_meta('brand'); ?>",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>",
        "price": "<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>",
        "priceValidUntil": "2019-12-31",
        "priceCurrency": "<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>",
        "url": "<?php echo $product->get_permalink(); ?>"
        },
      "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "reviewCount": "3"
        },
      "review": {
          "author": "Federico",
          "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "ratingValue": "5",
            "worstRating": "4"
          }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**For the "Brand":**

if it's a custom taxonomy (like wen using Woocommerce Brands plugin), you will hav to replace:

```
"brand": "<?php echo $product->get_meta('brand'); ?>",
```

by this line *(where the taxonomy is here '`product_brand`')*:

```
"brand": "<?php $brand = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_brand' ); $brand = reset($brand); echo $brand->name; ?>",
```

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, that works fine.
For the brand, is a custom field for each product. So with the original line works perfect.